# Menu Item Aliases stopped working Joomla 3.3.3

Tags: joomla-3.3.x, menu, menu-item, alias

I recently upgraded my site from Joomla 3.3.1 to Joomla 3.3.3.  When I did this the menu items in my footer that were aliases of other menu items stopped working.  The only one that still works points at the "main" menu.

Does anyone know if this is by design? If not, is there a work around?  Obviously I would like to keep the aliases in place so that if I need to change an address on the site I only have to change it in one place.

Thanks

Comment: Everything works on my test Joomla 3 website. There are menu menu items that points not only to the main menu. May be you are using some third party module for you footer menu?

Comment: I use a lot of aliases... but none of the updates had a problem. Try to "Rebuild"

Comment: Nothing unusual going on, the footer is just a div with 4 menus in it.  I have tried making the menu items of another type and then switching back, no luck.  Perhaps I will tear them all the way down along with the parent and see if that helps.  Thanks for the suggestions guys.

Comment: Update on this:  Aliases seem to work fine as long as the source or parent of the alias points to something contained within that joomla site.  If you make the parent an external URL and try to make an alias of of that menu item, then the alias fails.  This was definitely working before the upgrade from Joomla 3.3.1 to 3.3.3.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

You could always just create a duplicate menu module instead of creating a duplicate menu.  You can limit the levels shown to make sure you only see top level menu items for a footer.